# How do I have the text and xml files open in a new window/tab?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here is the code. I am fairly new to JavaScript and I'm learning more every day. This code is from an example from a textbook. Thank you for your responses. Another question I'd like to ask is how can I display the returned text in an unordered list? Would that be something to include in the html side of things or can it be done within the JavaScript file?

```js
window.addEventListener("load",initAll,false);
var xhr = false;

function initAll() {
 document.getElementById("makeTextRequest").addEventListener("click",getNewFile,false);
 document.getElementById("makeXMLRequest").addEventListener("click",getNewFile,false);
}

function getNewFile(evt) {
 makeRequest(this.href);
 evt.preventDefault();
}

function makeRequest(url) {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   try {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   catch (e) {
   }
  }
 }

 if (xhr) {
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange",showContents,false);
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send(null);
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById("updateArea").innerHTML = "Sorry, but I couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest";
 }
}

function showContents() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
   if (xhr.responseXML && xhr.responseXML.childNodes.length > 0) {
    var outMsg = getText(xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("choices")[0]);
   }
   else {
    var outMsg = xhr.responseText;
   }
  }
  else {
   var outMsg = "There was a problem with the request " + xhr.status;
  }
  document.getElementById("updateArea").innerHTML = outMsg;
 }
 
 function getText(inVal) {
  if (inVal.textContent) {
   return inVal.textContent;
  }
  return inVal.text;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you are making an AJAX request and are receiving XML.

In this case, I would:

1. Open up a new page with `window.open()`(returns a new Window object)
2. And then change the `document.body.innerHTML` of that new page to the XML you have

If you had a webpage that held the XML(maybe the server you are requesting to has one), you can just do:

`window.open("page.xml");`